# html/js Windows 8 People App (Facebook , Twitter) sharing anything except a URI

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I'm trying to use the Share Contract to share some content from a windows 8 app (written in html / js) to facebook and twitter using the People app.

I've taken a long hard look at the sample app (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Sharing-Content-Source-App-d9bffd84/sourcecode?fileId=43982&pathId=1680766409) and it appears that nothing other than a URI is supported. I'd love to be able to set a default message (which the user could of course edit) in both. Or some rich html, or something.

I've tried:

- text: only the mail app shows up
- image: just mail and skydrive html
- content: the people app shows up, but then errors out saying "the
  People app can't share this. Try sharing with a different app, like Mail."

With Facebook this isn't exactly fatal because a thumbnail and description is fetched from the URI, but if the user selects twitter, all you get is the url and the option to add a message: not a particularly good user experience.

It seems like something better than this *must* be possible. Any and all ideas deeply appreciated.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Twitter and Facebook SDK. As the SDK provide more features but please note share contract can't be integrate with SDKs. Just Google about how to post on Facebook and Twitter programmatically.

Comment: I agree you are probably right there, I was trying to be as msft-standard experience as possible, but it seems pretty unacceptable as it is. I wonder if they talked to any app developers while they were designing it.